# ConcurrentHashQueue in C#

Tags: c#, concurrency, cache

The `ConcurrentHashQueue` data structure is a FIFO queue that at the same time allows look-ups of items based on a key in O(1) like a dictionary. It can be used as a cache when the number of cached items is a constant and the eviction strategy is FIFO. This makes sense when the cost of computing/creating an evicted item is not so high to justify the book-keeping costs of a LRU cache.

This implementation is also intended to be thread-safe.

```
internal class ConcurrentHashQueue<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
    private readonly int _capacity;
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _map;
    private readonly Queue<TKey> _queue;

    public ConcurrentHashQueue(int capacity)
    {
        _capacity = capacity;
        _map = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity);
        _queue = new Queue<TKey>(capacity);
    }

    public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TValue> createValue)
    {
        TValue value;
        // first try to get the value without locking
        // ReSharper disable once InconsistentlySynchronizedField
        if (_map.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        // the value needs to be created and added
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            // recheck existence within critical section to avoid racing conditions
            if (_map.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            value = createValue();
            Add(key, value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (_map.Count == _capacity) // capacity reached
        {
            RemoveFirst();
        }
        _map.Add(key, value);
        _queue.Enqueue(key);
        Debug.Assert(_map.Count == _queue.Count, "The count of the queue should always equal to the count of the map.");
        Debug.Assert(_map.Count <= _capacity, "The count of items should never exceed the capacity.");
    }

    private void RemoveFirst()
    {
        TKey first = _queue.Dequeue();
        _map.Remove(first);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect a queue to implement IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection and, well, basically everything the built in [ConcurrentQueue class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) implements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call this a *Queue* but it does not behave like one. It's more like a strange dictionary that removes the first element that was added if the capacity exceeds.

A queue would have such methods as `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` for adding and getting elements but in this queue I need to know the key of an element in order to get it so there is no way of getting the first added element. A name like `FixedCapacityCollection` would be more appropriate.

Since this is a collection your class should also implement the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` interface so that it can be used with linq and loops if necessary.

Comment: It's a limited capacity dictionary that evicts items in FIFO order. I shall rename it to: `ConcurrentFifoDictionary`. I think this name covers all aspects.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a `List`, are you *forced* to provide a `capacity`? No you're not. I think it should be the same concerning your data structure. There are several occasions where you just don't know how many objects you'll have. Since the underlying `Queue` and `Dictionary` can very well adapt to increase your capacity, your data structure has nothing to fear by offering a default empty constructor.

I'm wondering why `GetOrAdd` exists. When you `Get` an object from a `Queue`, you should remove that object, IMO. So you should implement some kind of `Exists` method, and the client of your object will deal with the scenario where you could want to add an object if it doesn't exist already.

Finally, there is one *terrible* side effect in your code :

```
if (_map.Count == _capacity) // capacity reached
{
    RemoveFirst();
}
```

If you reach capacity, you should either expand your capacity, or throw an exception. Removing the first object is just a way to hide the problem. But if I use your class, I would **never** expect this situation if the queue was full.

Comment: I'm realizing now that I misnamed this class. Its intention is to serve as a cache where the caller exactly know the number of stored items. Therefore the capacity of the items is fixed. So it's really a FIFO cache (as opposed to a LRU cache). I shall rename the class, like it was already suggested by others.

Comment: @Dejan this is very similar to a Circular Buffer. The difference is that a circular buffer will typically block or error if you try to fill it when it's full.